# Formatação de array

Tags: javascript, array, node.js, formatação

Bom dia pessoal!
Eu estou com uma duvida sobre a formatação de um array no javascript.

Meu código está dessa forma.

```
var oidup = ['5006144', '5006146']; //valores oid especifica
var oids = ['1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.', '1.3.6.1.2.1.10.127.1.1.4.1.5.']; //propriedades oid para metrica 
var oidtotal = []; // array

var j = 0;
var k = 0;
var z = 0;
for (j = 0; j < oids.length; j++) { 
    for (k = 0; k < oids.length; k++) {
        oidtotal[z] = [oids[j] + oidup[k]];
        z += 1;
    }
}

console.log(oidtotal);
```

ele me retorna os valores da seguinte forma.

```
oidtotal = [
  [ '1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.5006144' ],     
  [ '1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.5006146' ],     
  [ '1.3.6.1.2.1.10.127.1.1.4.1.5.5006144' ],
  [ '1.3.6.1.2.1.10.127.1.1.4.1.5.5006146' ] 
]
```

Eu estou tentando formatar para que ele me retornasse dessa maneira.

```
 oidtotal = ['1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.5006144','1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.5006146','1.3.6.1.2.1.10.127.1.1.4.1.5.5006144','1.3.6.1.2.1.10.127.1.1.4.1.5.5006146']
```

Podem me auxiliar para conseguir entender como consigo fazer isso?

Fiz a tentativa de criar um novo array, e usar o método join, mas não consegui o resultado esperado.
Tentei realizar dessa forma.

```
formataroid[0] = oidtotal.join(['\',\'']);
```

Porem o resultado foi esse.

```
formtaroid = [
  "1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.5006144','1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.5006146','1.3.6.1.2.1.10.127.1.1.4.1.5.5006144','1.3.6.1.2.1.10.127.1.1.4.1.5.5006146"
]
```

Eu estou tentando utilizar o modulo net-snmp e o método `session.get(formataroid, function(error, varbinds)`

E ele aceita somente  string.
Como está na doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/net-snmp

Desde já, muito obrigado.

Comment: OK, temos o código, mas poderia tentar explicar textualmente o objetivo do código? Consigo chutar (e tentar adivinhar), mas sem uma descrição mais formal é meio difícil de ter certeza. Enfim, clique em **[edit]** para acrescentar essa informação à sua pergunta.

Comment: Onde está `oidtotal[z] = [oids[j] + oidup[k]];` troque por `oidtotal += oids[j] + oidup[k];` , acho que é isso.

Comment: Boa tarde Luiz, já coloquei a descrição, muito obrigado.


Augusto, dessa forma não funciona, porque me retorna sem o apostrofo e a virgula no final de cada indice. Dessa forma me retorna assim:

oidtotal = 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.50061441.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.50061461.3.6.1.2.1.10.127.1.1.4.1.5.50061441.3.6.1.2.1.10.127.1.1.4.1.5.5006146

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado a todos, consegui resolver, graças a sugestão do Augusto e fiz mais algumas incrementações e deu certo. Para quem estiver precisando de ajuda no mesmo assunto que eu, vou compartilhar o código.

```
var oidup = ['5006144', '5006146', ];
var oids = ['.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.', '.3.6.1.2.1.10.127.1.1.4.1.5.', '.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.', '.3.6.1.2.1.10.127.1.1.2.1.4.'];
var oidtotal = [];

var j = 0;
var k = 0;
var z = 0;
for (j = 0; j < oids.length; j++) {
    for (k = 0; k < oidup.length; k++) {
        oidtotal[z] = ['1'];
        oidtotal[z] += [oids[j] + oidup[k]];
        z += 1;
    }
}

console.log(oidtotal);
```

Eu removi o primeiro caracter do array oids e o adicionei no array oidtotal antes do calculo assim não corro o risco do array ficar com undefined e só depois os valores, e segui a sugestão do Augusto, porem adicionando o indice.

Obrigado a todos.